# mysql delete earlier datas if max(id) - min(id) > 50,000

Tags: mysql, sql, ssh

I have a table in which I need to keep the total number of rows within 50,000. This table includes an Id field (id is auto incremental).

How can I check if `max(id) - min(id) > 50,000`, then delete the earlier rows?

```
DELETE FROM news WHERE if (max(id) - min(id) > 50000)
```

This `query` will delete all the rows if `max(id) - min(id) > 50000`, what is the correct way? Ideally I need a one line command, excuse in SSH method. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE d 
FROM news AS d
  JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX(id)-50000 AS lim 
      FROM news
    ) AS m
    ON d.id < m.lim ;
```

The above will not leave exactly 50K rows of course, as there may be gaps in the `id` sequence. But I guess this is expected and not a problem. If you really want to leave exactly 50K rows, any statement will probably be less efficient. You can try this one:

```
DELETE d 
FROM news AS d
  JOIN
    ( SELECT id AS lim 
      FROM news
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 50000
    ) AS m
    ON d.id <= m.lim ;
```

Comment: exact same answer as me... just differs by some seconds... :)

Comment: @ypercube: Is your answer is faster then Jim's ?

Comment: @ypercube I understood your will be fast... :) , `+1` to your answer too. nested queries are slow that the reason. Am I correct?

Comment: @Grijesh: Test them and tell us :)

Comment: @ypercube Nested are slow then Join, I guess that is the reason.

Comment: @Grijesh The problem with Jim's answer (and my 2nd one) is that the `id` index has to be traversed from the max value and all the way down for 50K values (that's an index scan). And only then the deleting can start.

Answer (score 2):

```
Delete from news where id < max(id)-50000
```

Comment: This assumes that ids are contiguous.

Comment: It is giving error like : "#1111 - Invalid use of group function"

Comment: @Pankaj, i got the same error "#1111 - Invalid use of group function"

Comment: need a subselect for the max(id)

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM news 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50000)
```

Comment: @Grijesh: Why, because it will be too slow?

Comment: @ypercube I don't know.. Its understood to me! I have only this reason.